# Visual studio in English to target DevExpress in another language

Tags: c#, localization, devexpress

I am using Visual studio in English and I am developing an app for the Japanese market. I am using DevExpress and the Devexpress messages are displayed in English. Can I change this to Japanese.
For example using the the Quick acces tool bar in the ribbon Form will show "Show QuickAccess toolBar Above the Ribbon".  I want this to be displayed in Japanese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress uses satellite assemblies to handle localization.

For a complete tutorial - go [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5755).

Visual Studio has nothing to do with the language beeing shown. By defualt the shown language is the same as the one specified your are currently using in your Windows

Be awhare that the current culture (and available satellite assemblies) determines what language is show to end users.